# How can I substitute a magic word only when transcluding template without using #invoke?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm trying to make a template that shows the time it was placed. I tried this:

```
This is a template ({{<includeonly>subst:</includeonly>CURRENTTIMESTAMP}})
```

but when transcluded it would show up as `This is a template ({{subst:CURRENTTIMESTAMP}})` instead of substituting the timestamp. I then tried

```
This is a template ({{{{{|safesubst:}}}CURRENTTIMESTAMP}})
```

but that didn't substitute it; the timestamp would keep updating. Next, I tried

```
This is a template ({{<includeonly>{{{|safesubst:}}}</includeonly>CURRENTTIMESTAMP}})
```

but no dice.

I know it's possible with `{{#invoke:}}` but I don't have that option. Could someone help me out?

Comment: How would the template know when some page transcluding it was edited? You can subst the template, then your first example will work. Otherwise, where would you expect the timestamp to be stored?

Comment: @Tgr The objective is to have the template save the time when it's first placed down (transcluded _or_ substituted), as the wiki I'm working on doesn't know much about substitution.

Comment: Well, you are not going to be able to do that with plain transclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how templates are stored. If you recursively subst the template, the contents of the template are stored in the wikitext of the including page, with `CURRENTTIMESTAMP` replaced with the actual timestamp. If you do not subst the template, the wikitext will only contain `{{MyTemplate}}`, and the timestamp of the edit is not stored anywhere; when the the parser renders the article and encounters `CURRENTTIMESTAMP`, it will just use the current timestamp. There is no way around that, `#invoke` or not.

What you can do is make the timestamp into a parameter, so in the including page you would write `{{MyTemplate|{{subst:CURRENTTIMESTAMP}}}}` and then the timestamp gets stored in the page. You can create a wrapper template with that exact content so that users only have to type `{{subst:MyTemplateWrapper}}` which is a bit easier. You can even make the template show an error / add an error category when used without substing, although [that's a bit more involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Substitution#Making_templates_behave_differently_when_transcluded_or_substituted).

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll go with the second method you mentioned (`{{subst:TemplateWrapper}}`) and add an error message if transcluded. Since this has answered my question, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Actually, I found out that `{{{{{|safesubst:}}}CURRENTTIMESTAMP}}` worked better (edited to show that).